# Controlled access folder is blocking most actions

Tags: windows-10-v1709, controlled-folder-access

I updated my computer to Windows 10 Fall Creator (build 1709), and now I am suffering from the `Controlled Access Folder` feature. I would like to keep this featured enabled because of all its security and protection purposes; however, almost any action I want to take is being blocked by it. I couldn't use `atom` IDE to save my code; I couldn't use `gnuplot` to print and save my plots; I couldn't create new folders. For some of these, I was able to find the applications that needed permission and allowed them through the folder access control manually to restore normal operation. However, for some other operations I wasn't able to find all the necessary components to white-list.

Other people who updated don't seem to have any issues, and my issue is pretty annoying. Does anyone else experience this? Or perhaps, someone can suggest a way to keep this feature enabled while getting rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PowerShell script documented in the following page. You can quickly allow all (or selected) blocked apps.

[Allow all blocked apps to Controlled folder access (interactively) using PowerShell](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/use-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-windows-defender/#apps_all_ps)

The PowerShelll script shows the list of blocked apps (read from the event log) and allows you to whitelist them en masse.

[image]

Comment: Some blocked items do not show up on on the blocked list.

Answer (score 2):

You should review your Event Viewer logs for the event IDs: 5007; 1123; 1124. Specifically 1123 (Audited Events) and 1124 (Blocked Events).

If you need to fine tune the feature, then you should put it in audit mode and then monitor for events to determine [which programs need to be whitelisted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/threat-protection/windows-defender-exploit-guard/customize-controlled-folders-exploit-guard).

From within an administrative PowerShell window, the following command puts it in audit mode:

`Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess AuditMode`

The following command will fully enable controlled folder access once it is fine tuned:

`Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess Enabled`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/threat-protection/windows-defender-exploit-guard/evaluate-controlled-folder-access

Comment: Sorry this is a bit beyond my knowledge with windows. I am looking through Event Viewer and can't locate IDs: 1123 and 1124.

Comment: So I downloaded the file from the microsoft link so to only view the relevant IDs. Are you suggesting that I should regularly check this place and manually white-list the apps it blocks until I restore normal operation through out the whole windows environment? Isn't there a better way? Maybe a command that would white-list all executables currently installed?

Comment: @Ptheguy - what's the point of whitelisting all apps that You have on pc? In that case just turn off Windows Folder Protection - the result will be the same, but-and You will be without the protection.

Answer (score 0):

Add your IDE under all "an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall" under control panel. Ensure to add java.exe. move your database in a folder directly under your C drive. Move your programming project folder to  C drive also. This should work with no issues. Thank you.